# Detect being hovering over specific widgets in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

So currently in my GUI, I have many fields that need some explanation of what they do. I was wondering if there was a way to have a small window or secion popup if the user hovers the mouse over a certain kind of widget?

So I have this code:

```
class mainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.label1.setText("Name")
        self.lineEdit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.label2.setText("Age")
        self.lineEdit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
```

I would like a small popup window to show when I hover over `self.lineEdit1` and `self.lineEdit2` with different messages. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest and standard way is to use a tooltip. Every widget in Qt has a [toolTip](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop) property you can use

```
class mainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.label1.setText("Name")
        self.lineEdit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit1.setToolTip("This is a ToolTip")

        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.label2.setText("Age")
        self.lineEdit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit2.setToolTip("This is another ToolTip")
```